# Split the string at the particular occurrence of special character (+) using regex in Java

Tags: regex, split

I want to split the following string around +, but I couldn't succeed in getting the correct regex for this.

```
String input = "SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'";
```

I want to have a result like this

```
 [SOP3a'+bEOP3', SOP3b'+aEOP3']
```

In some cases I may have the following string

```
c+SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2
```

which should be split as

```
[c, SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2]
```

I have tried the following regex but it doesn't work.

```
input.split("(SOP[0-9](.*)EOP[0-9])*\\+((SOP)[0-9](.*)(EOP)[0-9])*");
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: another example string could be      c+SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2

Comment: `(SOP[0-9].*?EOP[0-9])\+(.+)`

Comment: Sorry @anubhava. Consider the following example: 

     `input = "SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'"` 

Now the criteria of splitting is to split around the same tags. That `+` should be picked up which is in between the same value of SOP tags. That is the string should be splited between SOP3 

`[SOP3a'+bEOP3', SOP3b'+aEOP3']`

Comment: @sln
It doesn't work.

Comment: No use wasting peoples time with games `(SOP[0-9].*?EOP[0-9])\+(.+)` Output:   **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 47 ) SOP1a+bEOP1+SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2   **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 11 ) SOP1a+bEOP1   **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 12 , len 35 ) SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* to match the string and by replacing it using captured group you can get the expected result :

```
(?m)(.*?)\+(SOP.*?$)
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dGGFqg/2)

Following is the code in Java that would work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'";
    String pattern = "(?m)(.*?)\\+(SOP.*?$)";

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

The `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` are the values that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @siam
In Java, i get an error at `\+` that it is an invalid escape sequence. When I replace it with `\\+`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @HasanBaig it should work. check java code for the `regex` [here](https://regex101.com/r/dGGFqg/2/codegen?language=java)

Comment: How can I access these separate elements?

Comment: Sorry about my naivety, but I am new to java. Can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer to contain the sample Java code that would probably help you. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Just to add, you do need to import `java.util.regex.Matcher` and `java.util.regex.Pattern` to run the sample code that I added.

Comment: @AliShahAhmed thanks for the edit and explanation :)

Comment: thanks @AliShahAhmed 
I tried your code and it worked well. I am just curious why it don't work if I exclude if-else structure ? It doesn't work at all when I try to access the value(s) without checking the condition `if(m.find())`.

Comment: @siam I just did it. Could you please also answer the question I just asked in my last comment ?

Comment: I would've but.. since I'm not a Java programmer, I've no knowledge about it. Maybe @AliShahAhmed can answer your question better. :)

Comment: I am not sure, but if you read the description of function `group()`, you'll see that it returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match. Calling the function `find()` finds the matches in the string, which is then returned by `group()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use `split` method?
And what are the rules? They are unclear to me.

Anyway, considering the regex you provided, I've only removed some unnecessary groups and I've found what you are looking for, however, instead of split, I just joined the matches as splitting it would generate some empty elements.

```js
const str = "SOP1a+bEOP1+SOP2SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'EOP2";
const regex = RegExp(/(SOP[0-9].*EOP[0-9])*\+(SOP[0-9].*EOP[0-9])*/)
const matches = str.match(regex);

console.log('Matches ', matches);
console.log([matches[1],matches[2]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Patrick
I need to use Split method. 
Consider the following example: 

`input = "SOP3a'+bEOP3'+SOP3b'+aEOP3'"` 

Now the criteria of splitting is to split around the same value of tags. That + should be picked up which is in between the same value of SOP tags. That is the string should be splited between SOP3 

`[SOP3a'+bEOP3', SOP3b'+aEOP3']`